# Accepting PDF documents and executable scripts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security

If I allow users to upload PDF documents (and only PDFs) is there any way a malicious user could include some executable script within or attached to the doc? What about standard word documents? What are some best practices if this is a requirement? (sorry that's totally 3 questions I know - but they all apply! ;))

I am using thoughtbot's paperclip plugin and I believe you can restrict by file type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whether or not something is "executable" matters less than whether or not you *try to execute* it. A file is just a sequence of bytes. Code is only dangerous if it's actually executed - the mere act of transferring a file, as long as the destination of that file is safe, is not something that can really cause harm. What could cause harm is if you are somehow invoking the uploaded file as a command, or passing it through some form of rendering engine that would accept directives from the file to execute actions.

Comment: So needless to say PDFing a document isn't going to do much if the file still contains some type of trigger that when downloaded and opened in a pdf viewer damages the client's OS, browser, hard drive, etc. I guess that's more my question. Any best practices to assist in these potential cases? I totally agree btw - the act of transferring is less of a concern then the actual execution. Thoughts?

Comment: There -are- exploits for Acrobat Reader etc. that can be delivered via PDF (see http://blog.security4all.be/2009/07/0-day-in-adobe-flash-also-executable.html for an example). One option (though not necessarily the most efficient) would be to process the PDF files via a library and 'print' them out to new PDF files that only contain a graphical rendition of the content, as opposed to any included 'dynamic' PDF elements. Of course, that means your users can't utilize such dynamic elements for legit reasons, but it sounds like you're mostly wanting visual content uploads.

Comment: Also, yes, there are security holes in MS Word documents as well, most of them dealing with macros or similar. Having some form of virus scan service that you run your uploads through isn't a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

Who are you trying to protect?

If it's yourself - you'll be fine, as per Dav's answer.  The danger comes from trying to execute or open code on the server.  So unless your server automates opening the file in Adobe you're cool.

If it's you're **users** then you're in trouble.  Adobe Acrobat is a hive of 0-day pdf exploits (as explained in the comments on Dav's answer).  Most to All can be mitigated by using an alternate pdf viewer like Foxit but you can't control that.  If you wanted to protect your users from PDF exploits and Word Macros you've got a serious challenge.  Virus Scanners can detect Word macros; but not Adobe exploits (not all of them anyway).